# Call an api within .subcribe next in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Essentially I am trying to edit a user, and calling the editUser method in my authService. Edit user in the auth service is just a HTTP post request.

```
this._authService.editUser(this.edit).subscribe(res=>{this.getUsers(this.params)}, (err)=>{alert(err)})
```

Now after editing the user, I wanna refresh the entire User list again. therefore I am calling the getUser method inside the .subscribe next field. The getUser method in the authservice is also a HTTP POST request.

```
getUsers(search){
    this._authService.getUser(search).subscribe(
      res => {
       
        this.persons = res
        
      },
      error => {
        if(error.status == 0) {
          alert("The servers are down right now, try again later")
        }
        else{
          alert(error.error.msg)
        }

      }
    );
  }
```

The problem with this is that it doesnt always refresh the persons list. Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: is this component implements `onPush` strategy? Does it update once you clicked on the component with your mouse? Asking because maybe you are missing a change detection there

Comment: please make sure you see two requests in the network tab of developer console when you edit a user. if you see both requests, it's related to your change detection

Comment: @RazRonen the function fires after pressing a button. So I am fairly sure it activates.

Comment: if adding `this.applicationRef.tick()` after `this.persons =res` resolve your problem you are missing a change detection trigger. applicationRef is a service, you can inject it in the constructor by: (applicationRef: ApplicationRef)

Comment: @Raz Ronen This did not fix the problem. It refreshes sometimes, but sometimes it doesnt. And I have to manually reload to see the changes. So the changes are actually being submitted just that the getUsers might be one step behind sometimes